# Unable to send parameters using Retrofit2 @GET and @Path

Tags: android, asp.net-core, kotlin, retrofit2

I want to send a get request with an ID param through to my asp.net rest api using the below code. The format I'm trying to achieve is https://randomwebapi.net/api/Tblathletes/id but instead the end result it always ends up being https://randomWebApi.net/api/Tblathletes/ which returns all athletes. It always omits the ID at the end. Is there another way I can achieve this format?

```
@GET("TblAthletes/{id}")
fun getAthlete(@Path("id")id:String?): Call<List<tblAthlete>>
```

Below is the code for making the call

```
    private fun getAthletesdata(athleteID: String?) {
//        val filter = HashMap<String?,String?>()
//        filter.put("Id",athleteID)
        val call = mAPIService?.getAthlete(athleteID)
        call?.enqueue(object : Callback<List<tblAthlete>> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<tblAthlete>>, response: Response<List<tblAthlete>>) {
                val athletes:List<tblAthlete> = response.body()!!
                txtName?.setText((athletes[0].name))
                txtSurname?.setText((athletes[0].surname))
                txtDOB?.setText((athletes[0].dob))
                txtAthleteNumber?.setText((athletes[0].athletenumber))
                txtID?.setText((athletes[0].athleteidno))
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<tblAthlete>>, t: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(this@EditAthleteActivity.context, t.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })

    }
```

Below is my asp.net code

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Tblathletegroup>>> GetTblathletegroup()
        {
            return await _context.Tblathletegroup.ToListAsync();
        }

        // GET: api/Tblathletegroups/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Tblathletegroup>> GetTblathletegroup(string id)
        {
            var tblathletegroup = await _context.Tblathletegroup.FindAsync(id);

            if (tblathletegroup == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return tblathletegroup;
        }
```

Below is The OKHttp Logs

```
2020-06-25 22:30:25.358 13749-13811/com.sprint_coach.shaun.sprint_coach D/OkHttp: --> GET https://RandomWebApi.net/api/TblAthletes/82ce9446-2776-41bd-bde8-3df6f924930a
2020-06-25 22:30:25.358 13749-13811/com.sprint_coach.shaun.sprint_coach D/OkHttp: --> END GET
2020-06-25 22:30:25.383 13749-13822/com.sprint_coach.shaun.sprint_coach D/OkHttp: --> GET https://RandomWebApi.net/api/TblAthletes/
2020-06-25 22:30:25.383 13749-13822/com.sprint_coach.shaun.sprint_coach D/OkHttp: --> END GET
2020-06-25 22:30:26.033 13749-13811/com.sprint_coach.shaun.sprint_coach D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK https://RandomWebApi.net/api/TblAthletes/82ce9446-2776-41bd-bde8-3df6f924930a (674ms)
2020-06-25 22:30:26.033 13749-13811/com.sprint_coach.shaun.sprint_coach D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
2020-06-25 22:30:26.033 13749-13811/com.sprint_coach.shaun.sprint_coach D/OkHttp: Vary: Accept-Encoding
2020-06-25 22:30:26.033 13749-13811/com.sprint_coach.shaun.sprint_coach D/OkHttp: Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
2020-06-25 22:30:26.034 13749-13811/com.sprint_coach.shaun.sprint_coach D/OkHttp: Request-Context: appId=cid-v1:037be9f0-7309-4880-8975-6ae211302d2b
2020-06-25 22:30:26.034 13749-13811/com.sprint_coach.shaun.sprint_coach D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
2020-06-25 22:30:26.034 13749-13811/com.sprint_coach.shaun.sprint_coach D/OkHttp: Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=7b498185396ab6e22ba34a59367270862958d11522d339239b2c110274a21354;Path=/;HttpOnly;Domain=RandomWebApi.net
2020-06-25 22:30:26.034 13749-13811/com.sprint_coach.shaun.sprint_coach D/OkHttp: Date: Thu, 25 Jun 2020 14:30:25 GMT
2020-06-25 22:30:26.039 13749-13811/com.sprint_coach.shaun.sprint_coach D/OkHttp: {"id":"82ce9446-2776-41bd-bde8-3df6f924930a","name":"Ronnie","surname":"Colman","dob":"1962","isDeleted":null,"modifiedUserId":null,"createdUserId":null,"createdDateTime":"2020-06-25T07:55:21","modifiedDateTime":null,"athleteNumber":"464664","athleteIdno":"643464","coachId":"Bob"}
2020-06-25 22:30:26.039 13749-13811/com.sprint_coach.shaun.sprint_coach D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (281-byte body)
2020-06-25 22:30:28.689 13749-13822/com.sprint_coach.shaun.sprint_coach D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK https://RandomWebApi.net/api/TblAthletes/ (3305ms)
2020-06-25 22:30:28.689 13749-13822/com.sprint_coach.shaun.sprint_coach D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
2020-06-25 22:30:28.689 13749-13822/com.sprint_coach.shaun.sprint_coach D/OkHttp: Vary: Accept-Encoding
2020-06-25 22:30:28.689 13749-13822/com.sprint_coach.shaun.sprint_coach D/OkHttp: Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
2020-06-25 22:30:28.689 13749-13822/com.sprint_coach.shaun.sprint_coach D/OkHttp: Request-Context: appId=cid-v1:037be9f0-7309-4880-8975-6ae211302d2b
2020-06-25 22:30:28.690 13749-13822/com.sprint_coach.shaun.sprint_coach D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
2020-06-25 22:30:28.690 13749-13822/com.sprint_coach.shaun.sprint_coach D/OkHttp: Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=7b498185396ab6e22ba34a59367270862958d11522d339239b2c110274a21354;Path=/;HttpOnly;Domain=RandomWebApi.net
2020-06-25 22:30:28.690 13749-13822/com.sprint_coach.shaun.sprint_coach D/OkHttp: Date: Thu, 25 Jun 2020 14:30:27 GMT
2020-06-25 22:30:28.698 13749-13822/com.sprint_coach.shaun.sprint_coach D/OkHttp: [{"id":"0f812b28-7285-11ea-b9a2-b42e9918ef25","name":"Shaun","surname":"Johnson","dob":"1992","isDeleted":null,"modifiedUserId":null,"createdUserId":null,"createdDateTime":"2020-03-30T20:50:40","modifiedDateTime":null,"athleteNumber":"6464","athleteIdno":"646464","coachId":"Bob"},{"id":"82ce9446-2776-41bd-bde8-3df6f924930a","name":"Ronnie","surname":"Colman","dob":"1962","isDeleted":null,"modifiedUserId":null,"createdUserId":null,"createdDateTime":"2020-06-25T07:55:21","modifiedDateTime":null,"athleteNumber":"464664","athleteIdno":"643464","coachId":"Bob"},{"id":"97171a8d-e2ca-454e-ad1e-491156c53cfc","name":"Bill","surname":"Burns","dob":"1985","isDeleted":null,"modifiedUserId":null,"createdUserId":null,"createdDateTime":"2020-06-25T10:09:41","modifiedDateTime":null,"athleteNumber":"222","athleteIdno":null,"coachId":"Bob"}]
2020-06-25 22:30:28.698 13749-13822/com.sprint_coach.shaun.sprint_coach D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (835-byte body)
```

Comment: probably you're sending null id. have you checked whether `athleteID` is null or not?

Comment: @denvercoder9 Thanks for the response. The id is definitely not null. I can see its populated in the watch and If I remove the "/" the id appends it self directly to the string eg. "https://randomWebApi.net/api/Tblathletes82ce9446-2776-41bd-bde8-3df6f924930a"

Comment: @Shaun It will be a lot easier to debug if you can share the OkHttp logs which show the request sent and the response received. Your retrofit code seems to be correct. The log will help to check determine the point of origin of the issue.

Comment: @KartikOhri Thanks for your input. I've added the logs. I see that its making multiple get requests for some reason but it does make the right request at some stage.

Comment: @Shaun This might be a good time to share your code if you are unable to debug the issue.

Comment: @KartikOhri I managed to get it working by changing the object type from Call<List<tblAthlete>>  to Call<tblAthlete>. Because I was only returning one row the the Java script being returned was not correct. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Shaun Great but This seems strange. I think the whatever the deeper issue here is, it is unresolved. You should try to debug that if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the object type from Call<List> to Call. Because I was only returning one row the the Java script being returned was not correct. Now it is working.